# Preload a background image in Javascript - without declaring CSS beforehand

Tags: javascript, css, image, background-image

I already know how to preload an image with Image.onload. But what about preloading a style.background image?

I need this for a game that's going to be preloading sprite sheets for different levels of a DHTML game.

I've had no success figuring out how to get style.background to use an Image object.

So how do I preload a style.background image, only with Javascript.

Comment: is there a reason why you can't preload it in the HTML itself and have it hidden in the CSS?

Comment: the key phrase in my question is "different levels" - I don't want the player to have to download all assets at once

Answer (score 1):

Just preload it the normal way.

The image will be cached in any case, regardless whether you use it as an `img` element, or as a `background-image` property.